# Understanding the equality $lim_{N \rightarrow \infty} \Sigma_{k= 0}^N \dfrac{(-1)^k}{t^k}= $1/(1+t)$

Tags: real-analysis

In my notes, I wrote the following: $lim_{N \rightarrow \infty} \Sigma_{k= 0}^N  \dfrac{(-1)^k}{t^k}= $1/(1+t)

Whereas If I do it by myself, I find: $lim_{N \rightarrow \infty} \Sigma_{k= 0}^N  \dfrac{(-1)^k}{t^k} = \Sigma_{k= 0}^{\infty} (-\dfrac{1}{t})^k = \dfrac{1}{1+\dfrac{1}{t}} $

I was wondering what I did wrong in my computation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

prove that for the finite sum is given $$\sum_{k=0}^N\frac{(-1)^k}{t^k}=\frac{t}{t+1}\Bigg (1-\left(-\frac{1}{t}\right)^{N+1} \Bigg)$$
the Limit of this sum is $$\frac{t}{t+1}$$ for $$|t|>1$$

Comment: How would one do that?

Comment: try induction to prove this

Comment: Thank You. Is the computation I made wrong?

Comment: the result must be $$\frac{t}{t+1}$$

Answer (score 1):

Your notes are wrong, probably a typo (wait, handwritten typo!) what you are doing now is right.

$$\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}\sum_{k=0}^{n}(-1)^kt^k = \frac{1}{1+t} $$

And

$$\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \sum_{k= 0}^n  \dfrac{(-1)^k}{t^k} = \dfrac{1}{1+\dfrac{1}{t}}$$

If you aren't yet satisfied,

$$\lim_{t \rightarrow \infty}\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \sum_{k= 0}^n  \dfrac{(-1)^k}{t^k} = \lim_{t \rightarrow \infty}\dfrac{1}{1+\dfrac{1}{t}}=1$$

And using expansion (Original sum) :

$$\lim_{t \rightarrow \infty}\Bigg (1-\frac{1}{t}+\frac{1}{t^2}-\frac{1}{t^3} \dots \infty \Bigg)=1$$

But ,

$$\lim_{t \rightarrow \infty} \frac{1}{1+t}=0 ~~; \text{ contradicts with original series.}$$

$$\text{Therefore :} ~\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \sum_{k= 0}^n  \dfrac{(-1)^k}{t^k} = \dfrac{1}{1+\dfrac{1}{t}}$$

Comment: According to Dr. Sonnhard Graubner, $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \sum_{k= 0}^n  \dfrac{(-1)^k}{t^k} = \dfrac{1}{1+t}$

Comment: @SylvesterStallone Read once again, fourth comment on his answer.

Comment: Yes, thank you.

Comment: @SylvesterStallone See my new edit to prove your book wrong.